# How can I multi thread my function? Using pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've a function with complexity (n-1)!
I would like to use multiple threads to calculate a length, then, if the length is lower, update the minimumLength value.

See my code (not the real one)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 10

struct params {
    int* minL_ptr;
    int** minLArray_ptr;
    int** numArray_ptr;
};

void *updateMin(void *void_param){
    struct params **params_ptr_ptr=(struct params **)(void_param);
    struct params *params_ptr=(struct params *)*params_ptr_ptr;
    int* minL_ptr=(int *)params_ptr->minL_ptr;
            printf("minL %d\n",*minL_ptr);

    int** minLArray_ptr=(int **)params_ptr->minLArray_ptr;
    int** numArray_ptr=(int **)params_ptr->numArray_ptr;

    int length=0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        length+=(*numArray_ptr)[i]; // in my real code it's not as easy as that

    if(length<=*minL_ptr){
        *minL_ptr=length;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            (*minLArray_ptr)[i]=(*numArray_ptr)[i];
    }

return NULL;
}


int main(void){


    pthread_t thread[12];

    srand(time(NULL));

    int minL=50000;
    int *minL_arr=calloc(N,sizeof(int));

    struct params *parameters=malloc(sizeof(struct params));
    parameters->minL_ptr=&minL;
    parameters->minLArray_ptr=&minL_arr;

    for(int i=0;i<50000;i++) { // (n-1)! example
        int *numArray=malloc(N*sizeof(int));
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            numArray[i]=rand()%1000; // generate random int array to sum later
        parameters->numArray_ptr=&numArray;


        pthread_create(&thread[i%11],NULL,updateMin,&parameters); // send parameters to a thread
    }
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);

    printf("Result : \n mL = %d\n",minL);
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%d ",minL_arr[i]);

    return 0;
 }
```

So I have some segmentation error, I tried to print minL value each time updateMin is called, but at a time it shows 0 and then a segmentation error.

Tried valgrind, and saw some IO error.

```
==1546== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1546== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1546== Using Valgrind-3.9.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1546== Command: ./test
==1546== Parent PID: 62488
==1546== 
==1546== Thread 2:
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x400882: updateMin (main.c:26)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Thread 4:
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x58B2E07: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==1546==    at 0x58B249B: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==1546==    by 0x58B656C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x58B24A5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:179)
==1546==    by 0x58B656C: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x58B65B8: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x58B2ECF: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1546==    at 0x58B2F4F: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1648)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)
==1546== 
==1546== Thread 1:
==1546== Invalid write of size 4
==1546==    at 0x4009A5: main (main.c:53)
==1546==  Address 0x5c16358 is 0 bytes after a block of size 40 alloc'd
==1546==    at 0x4C274A0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
==1546==    by 0x400959: main (main.c:51)
==1546== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 864, hi = 0.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.

==1546==    at 0x3805022C: report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:260)
==1546==    by 0x38050386: vgPlain_assert_fail (m_libcassert.c:340)
==1546==    by 0x3805C962: vgPlain_arena_malloc (m_mallocfree.c:301)
==1546==    by 0x38021374: vgMemCheck_new_block (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:377)
==1546==    by 0x380216AF: vgMemCheck_calloc (mc_malloc_wrappers.c:452)
==1546==    by 0x3809C522: vgPlain_scheduler (scheduler.c:1766)
==1546==    by 0x380AB4DC: run_a_thread_NORETURN (syswrap-linux.c:103)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable
==1546==    at 0x4C29590: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:618)
==1546==    by 0x4010F21: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:296)
==1546==    by 0x401162D: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:460)
==1546==    by 0x4E3ABD6: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (allocatestack.c:589)
==1546==    by 0x400A0E: main (main.c:57)

Thread 2: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DFB9: __lll_unlock_wake_private (lowlevellock.S:341)
==1546==    by 0x58B76B9: _L_unlock_1050 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B27B2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:2069)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 3: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DFB9: __lll_unlock_wake_private (lowlevellock.S:341)
==1546==    by 0x58B76B9: _L_unlock_1050 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B27B2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:2069)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 4: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DF8B: __lll_lock_wait_private (lowlevellock.S:95)
==1546==    by 0x58B769E: _L_lock_976 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B2752: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1325)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 5: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DFB9: __lll_unlock_wake_private (lowlevellock.S:341)
==1546==    by 0x58B76B9: _L_unlock_1050 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B27B2: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:2069)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 6: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DF8B: __lll_lock_wait_private (lowlevellock.S:95)
==1546==    by 0x58B769E: _L_lock_976 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B2752: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1325)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 7: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DF8B: __lll_lock_wait_private (lowlevellock.S:95)
==1546==    by 0x58B769E: _L_lock_976 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B2752: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1325)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)

Thread 8: status = VgTs_WaitSys
==1546==    at 0x595DF8B: __lll_lock_wait_private (lowlevellock.S:95)
==1546==    by 0x58B769E: _L_lock_976 (vfprintf.c:2333)
==1546==    by 0x58B2752: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1325)
==1546==    by 0x58BC768: printf (printf.c:33)
==1546==    by 0x40082D: updateMin (main.c:17)
==1546==    by 0x4E3A061: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==1546==    by 0x5951A3C: clone (clone.S:111)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

Where do you think is the problem?

Comment: At which line do you get the seg fault? What is the output from Valgrind?

Comment: I don't think that int can handle that value...

Comment: You're passing a pointer to a local variable (&parameters) which you then proceed to change (the object it is pointing to) and pass to the next thread. Problem is, the first thread may also see the changed value, the threads receive a pointer to the same object after all.

Comment: HAL9000 > modified the int value to 50000 before build

Comment: @BuellaGábor > added the valgrind output in main message

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson > Only the object minL and minLArray is modified (not each time, only when length<minL) , should I allocate them for each parameters I pass to the threads?

Comment: BTW, any reason why `length` is double in updateMin ?

Comment: It would also be cool, if line numbers printed by valgrind would match the source posted.  It mentions ` updateMin (main.c:27)` and such places.

Comment: `int minL=9999999999;`  ??????? 

How many bits wide is `int` on you platform?

Comment: And why do you intend to create 50000 threads? then overwrite the same twelve thread pointers? I don't understand

Comment: @BuellaGábor > mistakes. sorry. updated my main post.

Comment: @BuellaGábor > The reason I use one thread per calculation ( updateMin ) is because my real updateMin function is using a lot of resources and I would like to use my computer threads to get it faster. (as there is 50000 int array to calculate)

my program is supposed to :
find the minimal length of a lot of arrays (which corresponds to a serie of points in cartesian map)

Comment: Still, it would be helpful to see a valgrind output with matching line numbers.

Comment: About the number of threads: If you `N` CPU cores, it will be fine to run something like `N` or `2*N` or `4*N` threads for a problem, totally depending on the current problem, you can experiment with it. But 50000 threads ( unless you have 10000 CPU cores ) is not going to work I guess. It is so inefficienct. Switching between multiple threads means a little overhead. Usually it doesn't matter, but with 50000 threads, it does a lot.

Comment: about valgrind, It's one line more or not, sorry about that

I've created 12 pthread ( pthread_t thread[12] ), doesn't it means 12 threads? how should I do then?

Comment: Each time you call `pthread_create` it creates a new thread, and gives you back a pointer to thread data. In this, it always overwrites your pointers to the data of previously created threads. ( but those threads are still running, you just lose your pointer associated with them )

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the only problem, but this is definitely not right;

```
for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    numArray[i]=rand()%1000;   // looping j, indexing by i
```

You're looping `i` to 50000, so `numArray` which is 10 integers long will be written way out of bounds, giving all kinds of undefined behavior in the rest of the program.